# eth0 to wlan0 router stretch

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, networking, wifi

I have the following situation

[image]

I would like to make the Internet connection on `wlan0` of the Pi available to all devices connected on `eth0`.
I'am using Raspian Stretch,  predictable network interface names disabled, `/etc/network/interfaces` is empty, ip4 forwarding enabled, `/etc/dhcpcd` untouched.

The Pi receives the `eth0` config from the LAN side DHCP Server and the wlan0 config from the AP "Router".

Following several tutorials here and elsewhere routing traffic from `eth0` to `wlan0` should be straightforward. See, for example, this post [eth0 to wlan0 NAT router setup?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/79666/eth0-to-wlan0-nat-router-setup), this one [eth0 to wlan0 NAT router [duplicate]](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/79656/eth0-to-wlan0-nat-router) or this Cent OS based solution [CentOS / Redhat Linux Internet Connection Sharing](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-fedora-linux-internet-connection-sharing-howto/).
Definitions:

- SSID1: Subnet 192.168.1.0/24 GW: 192.168.1.1 (on Router in Image)
- SSID2: Subnet 192.168.2.0/24 GW: 192.168.2.1 (on PI:eth0)
- Host1: on Subnet 192.168.1.0/24 GW: 192.168.1.1 (on Router in image)

Unfortunately, none of those solutions which are basically all the same seem to work in the case abvove.

Core step is route traffic from eth0 to wlan0 using iptables

> sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE

I **am** able to do this:

- ping or access Host1 from 192.168.2.0/24 by webbrowser

I **am not** able to access any host on the internet from 192.168.2.0/24 or from the Pi itself

Looks like a gateway or a route is missing? 
The result of ip route

> $ip route
>   default via 192.168.2.1 dev eth0 src 192.168.2.1 metric 202
>   default via 192.168.43.1 dev wlan0 src 192.168.43.100 metric 303
>   192.168.2.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.1 metric 202
>   192.168.43.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.43.100 metric 303

Now I am at an end with my knowledge, what is missing and what should/could I do? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In your picture the ip address 192.168.2.1 is the same then GW=192.168.2.1. This isn't possible. What is AP "Router"? What subnet has wifi with ssid "SSID1"? What subnet has wifi with ssid "SSID2"? To what subnet belongs Host1? To what subnet belongs Test1? Please edit your question to update it.

Comment: What is the output of `ip route` on the Pi?

Comment: As has already been pointed out, and it case it was not clear enough, both networks set up "around" the wlan router are the same (192.168.2/24, I presume). Set it up so that you don't have duplicate network segments on any of the 3 networks shown there (SSID1, SSID2, pi to WLAN Router) and everything should start working fine.

Comment: My intention ist have only one Subnet on the right hand side of the Pi, ie. 192.168.2.0/24. The fact that there is another WLAN with SSID "SSID2" should be irrelevant. I can switch off "SSID2", connect all client through cable and have the same result.

Comment: The problem is not the name of the wireless networks. It's that the WLAN ROUTER has two overlapping network segments set up (both segments are 192.168.2.0/24). Take one of the segments and set it to 192.168.3.0/24, for example).  Also, I see another problem with the pi set up It's displaying two "default" GW. That can't be good (and will probably make it misbehave) so this line should be **gone** `default via 192.168.2.1 dev eth0 src 192.168.2.1 metric 202`.

Comment: Thank you eftshift0, problem SOLVED  Ihave disabled the WLAN "SSID2", so the eth0 interface on the pi is facing a single LAN based subnet 192.168.2.0/24  On the pi I have remove the first default route by   > Sudo ip route del 0/0 dev eth0

Comment: As soon as i add "sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE" the routing from 192.168.2.0/24 to the Internet works

Comment: Can you please answer your question with the solution to close this question?

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to solve this problem withe the help of the comments.
First i have disabled the wlan "SSID2". So the eth0 interface of the pi faces exactly one subnet 129.168.2.0/24. Alle devices are connectet using cables and a switch with dhcp cababilities.
The output of

```
> ip route
```

showed a default route for eth0 (added automatically by dhcpdcd)
Using

```
Sudo ip route del 0/0 dev eth0
```

got rid of that entry and as soon as i enabled routing by

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

the system worked as desired.
Case closed, Thank you.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.